# `vim` and `YouCompleteMe`

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I installed `vim` with python support from source.
Then I used `Vundle` to install `YouCompleteMe` with the option `--clang-completer`.
No other plugin is additionally installed by me and the clanglib is up to date. 
I set up the `.ycm_extra_conf.py` with the following:

```
import os
import ycm_core
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-w',
'-Wextra',
'-fexceptions',
'-DNDEBUG',
'-std=c++11',
'-x',
'c++',
'-isystem',
'../BoostParts',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/c++/4.9',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/c++/4.9/backward',
'-isystem',
'/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include',
'-isystem',
'/usr/local/include',
'-isystem',
'/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include-fixed',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include'
]
compilation_database_folder = ''

#the rest code from the original
```

(removed comments)
Beside the `Vundle` stuff in the .vimrc I also added this:

`let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf ='~/.ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf'`

Why do no popups show up, when I type in a cpp file with vim `#include <`, `[somenamespace]::` or use any of the member and pointer operators,

where you would suspect such behavior, such as `.` or `->`?

However if I type filenames or already typed words I get completion suggestions...

Comment: That plugin has a dedicated issue tracker: use it.

Comment: @romainl First thing to do is to not assume any errors made by the creator but by the user. But okay, if nobody answers I'll add the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple... The `.ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf` wasn't `.ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf`, it was more like `.ycm_extra_conf`. So I'll count this as a fail. Everything is fine now.

> **Make sure you check the most basic things first.**